# Update interface element to follow external Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty sure my question is standard but I did not find the answer. I created a CodePen to illustrate it : https://codepen.io/Hylectrif/pen/QWdoqNB?editors=1111.

I am actually trying to make my interface correspond to an external object by mapping one of it attributes. But my interface does not automatically update on change. I am probably missing a hook or something but I can't find out.

Thank for your help ☺

```
class Example{
  constructor(){
    this.r = [1, 2, 3]
  }  
  updateR = () =>{
    this.r.pop()
    alert(this.r)
  }
}

function Welcome(props) {
  const e = new Example();
  return <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={e.updateR}>yo</button>
    {
      e.r.map(bar => {
        return (<h1 key={bar}>{bar}</h1>)
      })
    }
  </React.Fragment>
}

const element = <Welcome />;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `e` is getting "reset" as `new Example()` on each render. You should use state in order to have your component update on click - although you'll have to do that in a way that returns a new object, rather than mutating an existing one as `e.updateR()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component never gets re-rendered, because you don't have any props changing and you don't have a state to trigger change detection.

To make this work you need to use the useState hook and update the object held inside that state. It's better to have functionality inside the component rather than another object.

Although it's not optimal something like this would work:

```
class Example{
  constructor(){
    this.r = [1, 2, 3]
  }  
  updateR = () =>{
    this.r.pop()
    alert(this.r)
    return this;
  }
}

function Welcome(props) {
  const [e, setE] = React.useState(new Example());  
  return <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={() => setE({...e.updateR()})}>yo</button>
    {
      e.r.map(bar => {
        return (<h1 key={bar}>{bar}</h1>)
      })
    }
  </React.Fragment>
}

const element = <Welcome />;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```